# App lifecycle and broadcast receivers

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, broadcasting

I am wondering what happens when you create a broadcast reciever from within your main activity (in my case a proximity alert receiver), and the app process is killed for some unknown reason?

I want my proximity alerts to be received in the broadcast recevier i register, regardless of my app state, will that happen or do i need to do something in particular to ensure that?

EDIT to clarify:

I have to register the receiver from within my app rather than via the manifest. Since i want multiple proximityalerts, for each (varying) location  i will need to create the receivers dynamically, since i need to register the receiver for each location, with a unique id, unfortunately.

code to create my intent/pendingintent/broadcastreceiver:

```
    double latitude = location.getLat();
    double longitude = location.getLon();
    Intent intent = new Intent(PROX_ALERT_INTENT_ID);
    PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(activity.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
    lm.addProximityAlert(
        latitude, // the latitude of the central point of the alert region
        longitude, // the longitude of the central point of the alert region
        POINT_RADIUS, // the radius of the central point of the alert region, in meters
        PROX_ALERT_EXPIRATION, // time for this proximity alert, in milliseconds, or -1 to indicate no                           expiration
        proximityIntent // will be used to generate an Intent to fire when entry to or exit from the alert region is detected
    );

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(PROX_ALERT_INTENT_ID);

    activity.registerReceiver(new ProximityIntentReceiver(location), filter);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have your `BroadcastReceivers` triggered regardless of your apps state then you should register them through your applications `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Heres how to do it.

1. Define a class that extends `BroadcastReceiver` and implement the `onReceive()` method.
   I see that you have already done that - `ProximityIntentReceiver` is that class.
2. In your AndroidManifest.xml file add:

   > ```
   > <application>
   > ...
   >     <receiver
   >         android:name=".MyReceiver"
   >         android:exported="false" >
   >         <intent-filter>
   >                <action android:name="my.app.ACTION" />
   >         </intent-filter>
   >     </receiver> 
   > </application>
   > ```

Where `MyReceiver` is the name of your receiver class (`ProximityIntentReceiver` in your case) and my.app.ACTION is the action that your receiver will listen for (in your case I'm guessing it's the value of `PROX_ALERT_INTENT_ID`).

**Note:** Saying that the name of your receiver is `.MyReceiver` assumes that it's located in the root package of your app. If that is not the case then you need to provide the path to that class starting from the root.

Comment: Hello there! Many thanks for taking the time to respond. I have edited my question to clarify. The problem is that i think i have to create it from within the app if i want to listen for multiple proximity alerts, since in that case i need to register multiple filters, and they will have to be dynamically created of course.

Comment: @Mathias: You will have to find some way to accomplish your aims by having your receivers registered in the manifest. You cannot dynamically register receivers *and* have them available when your app is not running. You can register for multiple proximity alerts with a single `BroadcastReceiver`, by packaging in different extras in each `PendingIntent`, using the 2nd parameter to `getBroadcast()` to supply a distinct ID value for the `PendingIntent` so they don't all wind up being the same object in the end.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for your time! Thats a tricky one. See, if i want to have multiple ProximityAlerts, i have to register them with different intent ID's. But i cannot know those beforehand (i don't know how many there will be, for one), so i can't see how i can put it in the manifest, since the intent-filters are static and i don't know beforehand what the intent-filter ID strings will be...

Comment: @Mathias: Please re-read my comment. Have *one* "intent-filter ID string". You do not need multiple "intent-filter ID string" values to have multiple outstanding `PendingIntent` objects. And, you do not need multiple "intent-filter ID strings" to receive broadcasts when one will suffice. You are inventing your own problem, then complaining when your problem is a problem.

Comment: Hey there again, Thanks for taking the time. The reason i think/thought i needed different ID's in my intent/pendingintents is various threads saying that unless you send in different intents, with different intent ID's to the "addProximityAlert", they will simply be overwritten and only the last one used. (see my code above). I.e. to have different simultaneous proximityalerts, you needed different intents with different ID's. I might be wrong though...

Answer (score 0):

@Mathias: The way I registered a broadcast receiver dynamically and being active even when the app is killed is by run a service and register the receiver from there. Hope it helps.